# C++ ampersand in function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, ampersand

I want to know that these definitions of functions are equal, ie there is no difference?

```
void fun1(int **X){....}
void fun2(int **&X){....}

int main(){
.....
fun1(Array);
fun2(Array);
.....
}
```

Or it is something change?

Comment: Pass by value versus pass by reference . They are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is obviously different, and the difference in functionality will greatly depend on how the functions are implemented. Passing a parameter to `fun2` and then writing to the parameter inside the body of the function will write to the referenced memory location, while passing the same parameter to `fun1` and writing to it inside the body of the function will leave the original parameter intact, since the passed parameter will just be a copy in a different memory location.